# jQuery: contains selector for <option>VALUE</option>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a class to the H1 tag that matches the current select option.

jQuery

```
    var option = $('#fruits').val()
    $("h1:contains(option)").addClass('selected')
```

html

```
<select>
    <option>Select One</option>
    <option>apple</option>
    <option>orange</option>
    <option>lemon</option>
</select>

<h1>apple</h1>
<h1>orange</h1>
<h1>lemon</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate `option` into the selector....

```
$("h1:contains('" + option + "')").addClass('selected')
```

Comment: It's preferred ( http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector ) to have single quotes on the outside and double on the inside for the contains selector.

Comment: The problem with this is you're including a string in the selector that comes from an input field without escaping it or anything. So it'll be quite easy to break.

Comment: Perfect... i need a drink now cause i been working on this issue for 2 hours.

Comment: @KevinB: I don't see where it states a preference. I do see in the example given in the docs that they have double on the outside.

Comment: It was through the jQuery forums, there was a case where using double quotes inside caused error but single quotes inside didn't. I'll have to look it up.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: The value is coming from a `<select>` input, so the values being inserted are controlled. If it was a text input, it would be a different story.

Comment: @KevinB: Funny thing is that with respect to quotes, the docs say... *"As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as bare words or surrounded by quotation marks."* ...but attribute values require quotes. Looks like they need to fix their docs.

Comment: @amnotiam I agree, I've been trying to find that post for a while, or to find out what the actual problem was to see if it was fixed in a recent version, I can't seem to recreate the issue. 99% of the time the quote order doesn't matter.

Comment: I [filed a bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11300) to clarify the quotes requirement for `:contains()`.

Comment: Hmm.... I wonder if what I ran into on the forums was actually a browser bug, due to the fact that `:contains` is done using the browser's built-in method when possible, and has since been fixed. It would explain why I can't re-create it.

Answer (score 0):

`option` is quoted, so being treated as a literal string.

```
$("h1:contains(" + option + ")").addClass('selected')
```

As a side note, you should use `.filter()` when using non-CSS selectors, as it's quicker.

```
$("h1").filter(":contains(" + option + ")").addClass('selected')
```